# Is a connected graph uniquely determined by its weighted 2-step graph?

Tags: graph-theory

This is an extension of a previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876336/is-a-graph-uniquely-determined-by-its-weighted-2-step-graph/876357#876357.  In that question I asked about arbitrary graphs; in this question I restrict to connected graphs.  Here are the details:

Let $G$ be an undirected graph.  Define the *2-step* graph $G^{(2)}$ of $G$ to be the weighted graph whose vertices are the same as those of $G$ but whose edges correspond to 2-step paths in $G$.  Thus the weight of an edge $(u,v)$ is the number of distinct vertices $w$ such that $(u,w)$ and $(w,v)$ are both edges in $G$.  (In particular, the weight of $(u,u)$ is the degree of $u$ for every vertex $u$.)  My question:

> Are there two connected, non-isomorphic graphs $G$ and $H$ such that $G^{(2)}$ is isomorphic to $H^{(2)}$?

My intuition says that the answer should be "yes", but I'm unable to construct an example.

Comment: You would like an example with simple graphs, I assume?

Comment: @Studentmath Yes.

Comment: If connected graphs were so easily determined, the isomorphism problem for them would be decided in polynomial time --- but that's widely believed to be impossible, so surely there are counterexamples.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this is equivalent to asking whether two different irreducible, 0-1 matrices may have the same equivalent $A^2$ matrix?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do you have a specific polynomial time algorithm in mind for determining whether or not the $2$-step graphs are isomorphic?  As far as I can tell the isomorphism problem for the $2$-step graphs is just as hard (maybe harder?) than the isomorphism problem for the original graphs.

Comment: @Studentmath That is true in the sense that the adjacency matrix of the $2$-step graph is the square of the adjacency matrix of the original graph.  But to turn it into a straight linear algebra problem you must include the condition that the irreducible $0-1$ matrices are symmetric ($G$ and $H$ are undirected) and have $0$'s along the diagonal ($G$ and $H$ are simple).

Comment: I think I misunderstood the problem. Sorry.

Comment: I wonder whether there is anything to be learned from isospectral graphs?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I had the same thought and even checked some examples of isospectral graphs that I found online, with no success.  But as Studentmath pointed out this question is in a sense about characterizing square roots of certain matrices, so spectral theory seem relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample can be constructed as follows. Let $G$ be the graph of a hexagonal pyramid and $H$ be that of a pair of tetrahedra sharing one common vertex. Then, $G^2$ and $H^2$ are isomorphic while $G$ and $H$ themselves are not. Indeed, $G$ has a simple $6$-cycle but $H$ has not.
[image]